# Can you explain to me how to apply Policy updates in a Policy Gradient algorithm ? (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning

I code a Policy Gradient algorithm in python with Tensorflow and I would like to know how to modify the neural network (updating the Policy).

My current code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from random import *
import sys
import io

seed(43)


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # Target: 2    Player: 1    Empty: 0
        self.grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    def gen_target(self):
        while True:
            y = randint(0, len(self.grid) - 1)
            x = randint(0, len(self.grid[y]) - 1)
            self.grid[y][x] = 2 if self.grid[y][x] != 1 else 1
            if self.grid[y][x] == 2:
                break
        return x, y

    def gen_player(self, x=None, y=None):
        if x and y:
            self.grid[y][x] = 1
        else:
            y = randint(0, len(self.grid) - 1)
            x = randint(0, len(self.grid[y]) - 1)
            self.grid[y][x] = 1
            return x, y

    @staticmethod
    def flatten(vector):
        return tf.reshape(tf.constant(vector, dtype=tf.float32), shape=(-1,)).numpy().tolist()

    def display(self):
        print(' ' + '―' * (len(self.grid[0]) * 3 - 2))
        for row in self.grid:
            row_str = '│' + ' '.join(f'{val:3}' for val in row) + '  │'
            print(row_str)

    @staticmethod
    def create_nn(input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_size,)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='softmax')
        ])
        return model

    def predict(self, model, state):
        stdout_temp = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
        prediction = model.predict([self.flatten(state)]).tolist()[0]
        sys.stdout = stdout_temp
        return prediction

    @staticmethod
    def choose_action(output):
        # Choose action with probability
        return choices([0, 1, 2, 3], output)[0]

    @staticmethod
    def is_valid(grid, pos):
        if 0 <= pos[0] <= len(grid) - 1 and 0 <= pos[1] <= len(grid[pos[0]]) - 1:
            return True
        return False

    def is_finish(self):
        return True if 2. not in self.flatten(self.grid) else False

    def move(self, action, x, y):
        r = 0  # Reward
        new_x = x + (1 if action == 1 else -1 if action == 3 else 0)
        new_y = y + (1 if action == 2 else -1 if action == 0 else 0)

        # Verify if action is valid
        if 0 <= new_y <= len(self.grid) - 1 and 0 <= new_x <= len(self.grid[new_y]) - 1:
            self.grid[new_y][new_x] = 1
            self.grid[y][x] = 0
            r = 1 if self.is_finish() else 0
        else:
            new_x, new_y = x, y
        # self.display()
        return new_x, new_y, r


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.game = Game()
        # Real position is (5,5)
        self.x = 4
        self.y = 4
        self.gamma = 0.99
        self.lr = 0.01
        self.game.gen_player(self.x, self.y)
        self.game.gen_target()
        self.model = self.game.create_nn(25, 1, 4)
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.lr)
        self.train()

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 4
        self.y = 4
        self.game.__init__()
        self.game.gen_player(self.x, self.y)
        self.game.gen_target()

    def train(self, num_episodes=10):
        episodes = []
        # Training loop
        for episode in range(num_episodes):
            episode = []
            while not self.game.is_finish():
                prediction = self.game.predict(self.model, self.game.grid)
                action = self.game.choose_action(prediction)
                self.x, self.y, r = self.game.move(action, self.x, self.y)
                episode.append([self.game.flatten(self.game.grid), action, r, 0])
            for e, i in enumerate(episode):
                i[3] += i[2]
                for e2, j in enumerate(range(e + 1, len(episode))):
                    i[3] += episode[j][2] * self.gamma ** (e2 + 1)
            episodes.append(episode)
            self.reset()
```

I coded the beginning of the algorithm, I just need to update the Policy